# Get latest record for multiple ids in psql

Tags: psql

I have a table where I have multiple records for the same id. I would like to get the latest record for each id using some where clause.
Sample table records

```
 vendor_id |    data    |         created_at         | id 
-----------+------------+----------------------------+----
         1 | some-data  | 2014-01-12 16:32:54.084505 |  2
 vendor_id |    data    |         created_at         | id 
-----------+------------+----------------------------+----
         1 | Notsome-dat| 2014-01-13 16:32:54.084505 |  3
```

I have multiple vendors with same data. So I want to get all the latest records for all the vendors where I can filter it with data. I have been using following query

```
SELECT VENDOR_ID,MAX(CREATED_AT) FROM TABLE WHERE DATA ILIKE '%Not some%'GROUP BY VENDOR_ID;
```

However, this query also gives me the vendor_id where they have "Not some" data in their second latest record not the latest one.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  DISTINCT

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ON (vendor_id) data  
FROM TABLE 
ORDER  BY vendor_id, "created_at" DESC;
```